# What's the idiomatic way to fake __hash__() for dicts?

Tags: python, python-3.x

EDIT: as @BrenBarn pointed out, the original didn't make sense.

Given a list of dicts (courtesy of `csv.DictReader`--they all have `str` keys and values) it'd be nice to remove duplicates by stuffing them all in a set, but this can't be done directly since `dict` isn't hashable. Some [existing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151658/python-hashable-dicts) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462119/lookup-table-for-unhashable-in-python) touch on *how* to fake `__hash__()` for sets/dicts but don't address which way *should* be preferred.

```
# i. concise but ugly round trip
filtered = [eval(x) for x in {repr(d) for d in pile_o_dicts}]

# ii. wordy but avoids round trip
filtered = []
keys = set()
for d in pile_o_dicts:
    key = str(d)
    if key not in keys:
        keys.add(key)
        filtered.append(d)

# iii. introducing another class for this seems Java-like?
filtered = {hashable_dict(x) for x in pile_o_dicts}

# iv. something else entirely
```

In the spirit of the [Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) what's the "obvious way to do it"?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  Are you looking for [a frozen dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703599/what-would-be-a-frozen-dict) (i.e., one that could be used as a key in another dict)?  Your code examples don't make much sense (e.g., your first one just recreates the original `pile_o_dicts`).

Comment: Not that this is the preferred solution or anything, but in your first example you can avoid the "round-trip" of eval'ing back the dict by just use a dict comprehension: `{repr(d):d for d in pile_o_dicts}.values()` instead of a set + a list comp with evals

Comment: @BrenBarn you're right, edited into something (hopefully!) sensible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The artfully named pile_o_dicts can be converted to a canonical form by sorting their *items* lists:

```
 groups = {}
 for d in pile_o_dicts:
     k = tuple(sorted(d.items()))
     groups.setdefault(k, []).append(d)
```

This will group identical dictionaries together.

FWIW, the technique of using `sorted(d.items())` is currently used in the standard library for functools.lru_cache() in order to recognize function calls that have the same keyword arguments.  IOW, this technique is tried and true :-)

Comment: Hard to compete with the standard library.

Answer (score 4):

Based on your example code, I take your question to be something slightly different from what you literally say. You don't actually want to override `__hash__()` -- you just want to filter out duplicates in linear time, right? So you need to ensure the following for each dictionary: 1) every key-value pair is represented, and 2) they are represented in a stable order. You *could* use a sorted tuple of key-value pairs, but instead, I would suggest using `frozenset`. `frozenset`s are hashable, and they avoid the overhead of sorting, which should improve performance (as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6014481/577088) seems to confirm). The downside is that they take up more memory than tuples, so there is a space/time tradeoff here.

Also, your code uses sets to do the filtering, but that doesn't make a lot of sense. There's no need for that ugly `eval` step if you use a dictionary:

```
filtered = {frozenset(d.iteritems()):d for d in pile_o_dicts}.values()
```

Or in Python 3, assuming you want a list rather than a dictionary view:

```
filtered = list({frozenset(d.items()):d for d in pile_o_dicts}.values())
```

These are both bit clunky. For readability, consider breaking it into two lines:

```
dict_o_dicts = {frozenset(d.iteritems()):d for d in pile_o_dicts}
filtered = dict_o_dicts.values()
```

The alternative is an ordered tuple of tuples:

```
filtered = {tuple(sorted(d.iteritems())):d for d in pile_o_dicts}.values()
```

And a final note: don't use `repr` for this. Dictionaries that evaluate as equal can have different representations:

```
>>> d1 = {str(i):str(i) for i in range(300)}
>>> d2 = {str(i):str(i) for i in range(299, -1, -1)}
>>> d1 == d2
True
>>> repr(d1) == repr(d2)
False
```

Answer (score 2):

If the dicts all have the same keys, you can use a `namedtuple`

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> nt = namedtuple('nt', pile_o_dicts[0])
>>> set(nt(**d) for d in pile_o_dicts)
```